# How to create XML object from string using xml-mapping in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, mapping

I'm using xml-mapping in Ruby (on Sinatra) for some XML stuff. Generally I follow this tutorial: http://xml-mapping.rubyforge.org/. I can create objects and write them to XML strings using

```
login.save_to_xml.to_s
```

But when I try

```
login = Login.load_from_xml(xml_string)
```

I get the following error:

```
XML::MappingError - no value, and no default value: Attribute username not set (XXPathError: path not found: username):
```

Here is the XML string I receive:

```
<login><username>ali</username><password>baba</password></login>
```

This is what the class looks like:

```
class Login
  include XML::Mapping

  text_node :username, "username"
  text_node :password, "password"
end
```

So the class name is the same, the nodes are named the same. I actually get the exact same string when I create an instance of my object and fill it with ali/baba:

```
test = Login.new
test.username = "ali"
test.password = "baba"
p test.save_to_xml.to_s

<login><username>ali</username><password>baba</password></login>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,
MrB

EDIT:

When I do

```
test = login.save_to_xml
```

And then

```
login = Login.load_from_xml(test)
```

it works. So the problem seems to be that I'm passing a string, while the method is expecting.. well, something else. There is definitely a load_from_xml(string) method in the rubydocs, so not sure what to pass here. I guess I need some kind of reverse to_s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you save_to_xml creates a REXML::Element.  Since that works, you may want to try:

```
Login.load_from_xml(REXML::Document.new(xml_string).root)
```

See the section on "choice_node" for a more detailed example http://xml-mapping.rubyforge.org/